# How to use createTrackBar() in OpenCV Android?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am developing image processing application in OpenCV with Android.
I want to use CvCreateTrackBar() method of opencv in android. How to use it?

Answer (score 2):

You must use Android GUI for this (you can't use OpenCV's HighGUI on Android). In your situation you can just use widget called [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html).